# Ubuntu Forums password.

Tags: security

I was wondering if anyone could tell me the format of the passwords for Ubuntu Forums. I am a member but haven't been online for quite a while and have forgotten which of my passwords I have used. If I know the minimum length and if it requires capitals or symbols, I should be able to remember. Obviously I am in a hurry to secure my other accounts with the recent breach.

Comment: Thanks for answers so far. Long term I will need to change all of my passwords. Got a lot on at the moment though and just want to focus on the most at risk. Does anyone know if they accept passwords less than 8 characters? If so I know which one it is.

Comment: I signed up sometime in 2007. My password has seven characters.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a quick look at an archived version of the site (via http://web.archive.org) but can't find any reference to any specific password requirements. The FAQs themselves seem unavailable (It looks like there was some script on there to reveal individual sections that wasn't preserved in the archived copy) and nothing is mentioned on the registration page either.

That said, if you're worried about any of your passwords being threatened, I'd suggest changing them anyway. Even down to changing anything that may have been somewhat similar. It's a pain I know, but best practice whenever you think one of your passwords could have been compromised.